# доступ из пода к внешней БД

Tags: kubernetes

Есть тривиальная задача $subject.

Кубик инициирован :
 `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.16.0.0/16` 
(10.244.0.0/16 не хочу).

В документации: [Services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) указано, что достичь этого можно с помощью сервиса без селектора.
Создаю манифест:

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-pgsql
  namespace: default
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.0.2.106
    ports:
    - port: 5432
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-pgsql
  namespace: default
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 5432
```

Результат:

```html
root@KuberM:~/.docker/yaml# kubectl get svc external-pgsql
NAME             CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
external-pgsql   10.10.120.81   <none>        5432/TCP   14s
root@KuberM:~/.docker/yaml# kubectl get ep external-pgsql
NAME             ENDPOINTS         AGE
external-pgsql   10.0.2.106:5432   32s
root@KuberM:~/.docker/yaml# kubectl describe service external-pgsql
Name:                   external-pgsql
Namespace:              default
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            <none>
Selector:               <none>
Type:                   ClusterIP
IP:                     10.10.120.81
Port:                   <unset> 5432/TCP
Endpoints:              10.0.2.106:5432
Session Affinity:       None
Events:                 <none>
```

Запускаю сервис (с hostNetwork: `true` соннект на `10.0.2.106` работает), захожу в контейнер и запускаю `psql -h 10.10.120.81 -U pgsql postgres` - не работает. 
Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: Попробуйте указать targetPort в spec. И подтвердите, пожалуйста, что получается подключиться в обход сервиса в той же конфигурации, в которой предполагается работа.

Comment: `root@KuberN2:/# psql -h 10.0.2.106 -U pgsql postgres
Password for user pgsql:
psql (9.3.18, server 9.6.3)
WARNING: psql major version 9.3, server major version 9.6.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
идентичный сервис с hostNetwork: true`

Comment: Наскольк понимаю, вы планируете подключаться из пода. Пока я не до конца понимаю, как с этим всем связан hostNetwork, можеет пояснить?

Comment: targetPort  не помогло , HostNetwork как маршрутизация до внешней сети

Comment: `apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-pgsql
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
`

Answer (score 1):

нужно использовать определённый диапазон  для фланнел 10.244.0.0/16

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста на примере, как  это можно использовать.